# Stop Button Text Changing on All Buttons

Tags: jquery, html, button, toggle, slidetoggle

```
$('.entry-content #toggle').click(function() {

var elem = $('#toggle').text();

if (elem == 'Read More') {

$('.entry #toggle').text('Read Less');

} else {

$('.entry #toggle').text('Read More'); 

}

});
```

This jQuery changes the button text on all buttons on each article on the archive page. I only want it to change the button which is clicked.

```
<div id="toggle" class="btn">Read More</div>

<div class="text" />
```

Update 1 :  I only want to add the button if there's 2 or more paragraphs. I assume i can use .after some how.

Update 2 :

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {

$(this).closest('.post').find('.text').slideToggle();

$(this).text(function( i, v ) {

   return v === 'Read More' ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More'


      });
});
```

Comment: ID should be unique on context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference your own button inside the event.

```
$('.entry-content #toggle').click(function() {

var elem = $(this).text();

if (elem == 'Read More') {

$(this).text('Read Less');

} else {

$(this).text('Read More'); 

}

});
```

Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Wish i understood jQuery like you Diego . I've spent 2 days trying to learn. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad i could help, and keep learning! JS is an awesome puzzle to work with!

Comment: Just 1 more question if you have time please. I only want to add the button if there's 2 or more paragraphs. I assume i can use .after some how.

Comment: You could use the length of your text or you can dig into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336264/paragraphs-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {

    var elem = $(this).text();

    if (elem == 'Read More') {
        $(this).text('Read Less');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Read More'); 
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle" class="btn">Read More</div>

<div class="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplified code.

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).text(function(i, v){
       return v === 'Read More' ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle" class="btn">Read More</div>

<div class="text" />
```

Comment: Could you use that with .slideUp(); and .slideDown();