# How to get a list of paragraphs/elements in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to keep count of paragraphs in my ckeditor but I am failing to keep count of them can someone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paragraphs in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336264/paragraphs-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you have any sample code of what you have tried so far, which failed for you?

Comment: I tried to searching the net and I've found nothing.