# how can i get a listbox in my Word counter?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an online word counter. HTML+JS.

I tried inserting a calculation based on the words counted. For example if we have 156 words, I would like to have 2 choices to multiply "156".Select list box "X 2", "X 3" and get result selected in a box => RESULT ► 312

How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please write the code that you've already tried.

Comment: var words = input.value.match(/\b[-?(\w+)?]+\b/gi);
  // console.log(words);
  if (words) {
    wordCount.innerHTML = words.length;
  } else {
    wordCount.innerHTML = 0;
  }

Comment: I also have the html, js and css files but i don't know how to share them here...

Answer (score 0):

The answer matches with the following phrase.

> For example if we have 156 words, I would like to have 2 choices to
>   multiply "156".Select list box "X 2", "X 3" and get result selected in
>   a box => RESULT ► 312

```js
$('.selectpicker').change(calcVal);

function calcVal() {
    var p = $(this).parent().parent()
    var m = p.find('input.txtMult')
    var mul = parseInt($(m[0]).val())
  $("#grandTotal").html($(this).children(':checked').data('cubics') * mul)
}

// call on document load
calcVal();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="" class="txtMult"/>

    <select class="selectpicker">
    <option data-cubics='2'>X 2</option>
    <option data-cubics='3'>X 3</option>
</select>
    <span id="grandTotal">Value Shows here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to share my files with you?
How to get result in a result zone under PARAGRAPHES ?
In fact, i don't need an input zone. The mulpilier must take the word counted "result" by the "X3" or X2" and show result as "text" (under paragraphes)

Comment: Can we share our emails Isuru Dilshan? To share the source code i wrote?

Comment: You can put your code in the question area. Just go and edit it. There is a button for codes

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*
 **
 ** User stories:
 ** - Shows number of characters, words, sentences, paragraphs - Done
 ** - Show reading time - Done
 ** - Show keyword count - Done
 ** - Show reading level (Optional - how?) - Done
 ** - Above data should change/appear on every keypress - Done
 **
 */

// Readability (Mashape) API Key for testing: PQ4FOFuaR6mshI6qpnQKQvkDZQXjp1o6Zcqjsnug7GvNggTzUE

"use strict";
var input = document.querySelectorAll('textarea')[0],
  characterCount = document.querySelector('#characterCount'),
  wordCount = document.querySelector('#wordCount'),
  sentenceCount = document.querySelector('#sentenceCount'),
  paragraphCount = document.querySelector('#paragraphCount'),
  readingTime = document.querySelector('#readingTime'),
  readability = document.querySelector('#readability'),
  keywordsDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.keywords')[0],
  topKeywords = document.querySelector('#topKeywords');

$('.selectpicker').change(calcVal);

function calcVal() {
    var p = $(this).parent().parent()
    var m = p.find('input.txtMult')
    var mul = parseInt($(m[0]).val())
  $("#grandTotal").html($(this).children(':checked').data('cubics') * mul)
}

// call on document load
calcVal();

// updating the displayed stats after every keypress
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  
  //keeping the console clean to make only the latest data visible
  console.clear();
  

  // character count
  // just displaying the input length as everything is a character
  characterCount.innerHTML = input.value.length;
  

  // word count using \w metacharacter - replacing this with .* to match anything between word boundaries since it was not taking 'a' as a word.
  // this is a masterstroke - to count words with any number of hyphens as one word
  // [-?(\w+)?]+ looks for hyphen and a word (we make both optional with ?). + at the end makes it a repeated pattern
  // \b is word boundary metacharacter
  var words = input.value.match(/\b[-?(\w+)?]+\b/gi);
  // console.log(words);
  if (words) {
    wordCount.innerHTML = words.length;
  } else {
    wordCount.innerHTML = 0;
  }


  // sentence count using ./!/? as sentense separators
  if (words) {
    var sentences = input.value.split(/[.|!|?]+/g);
    console.log(sentences);
    sentenceCount.innerHTML = sentences.length - 1;
  } else {
    sentenceCount.innerHTML = 0;
  }


  // paragraph count from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3336537
  if (words) {
    // \n$ takes care of empty lines: lines with no characters, and only \n are not paragraphs
    // and need to be replaced with empty string
    var paragraphs = input.value.replace(/\n$/gm, '').split(/\n/);
    paragraphCount.innerHTML = paragraphs.length;
  } else {
    paragraphCount.innerHTML = 0;
  }
  // console.log(paragraphs);


  // reading time based on 150 words/minute
  if (words) {
    var seconds = Math.floor(words.length *  60 / 150);
    // need to convert seconds to minutes and hours
    if (seconds > 59) {
      var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
      seconds = seconds - minutes*60;
      readingTime.innerHTML = minutes + "m "+ seconds + "s";
    } else {
      readingTime.innerHTML = seconds + "s";
    }
  } else {
    readingTime.innerHTML = "0s";
  }


  // finding out top keywords and their count
  // step-1: remove all the stop words
  // step-2: form an object with keywords and their count
  // step-3: sort the object by first converting it to a 2D array
  // step-4: display top 4 keywords and their count
  
  if (words) {
    
    // step-1: removing all the stop words
    var nonStopWords = [];
    var stopWords = ["à","allô","aucuns","auriez","auxdits","aviez","ayons","bof","çà","certaines","chez","comment","da","desquels","deviez","devras","doit","dues","dût","es","êtes","eurêka","excepté","fouchtra","fûmes","ho","hurrah","laquelle","leur","mazette","mâtin","ne","nulle","or","outre","pas","plein","pourraient","pourvu","pouviez","puis","pussent","que","quoi","saperlipopette","serait","sien","sommes","ta","telles","touchant","une","veuillez","voilà","voudrez","voulante","voulue","vôtre afin","alors","auquel","aurions","auxquelles","avions","aïe","boum","car","certains","chic","concernant","dans","devaient","devions","devrez","doive","duquel","eh","et","étiez","eus","eûmes","furent","fût","holà","hé","le","leurs","me","miséricorde","ni","nulles","ôté","palsambleu","patatras","plouf","pourrais","pouvaient","pouvions","puisque","put","quel","quoique","sapristi","seras","sienne","son","tandis","tels","tous","unième","veuillons","vos","voudriez","voulantes","voulues","vôtres ah","apr.","aura","aurons","auxquels","avoir","bah","bravissimo","ce","ces","chiche","contre","de","devais","devoir","devriez","doivent","durant","elle","étaient","étions","eusse","eût","fus","fûtes","hop","il","ledit","lorsque","merci","moi","nonobstant","nuls","ou","pan","pechère","plus","pourrait","pouvais","pouvoir","puisse","pécaïre","quelle","rataplan","sauf","serez","siennes","sont","tant","tes","tout","unièmes","veulent","votre","voudrions","voulants","voulurent","zut ai","as","aurai","auront","avaient","avons","basta","bravo","ceci","cet","chouette","corbleu","debout","devait","devons","devrions","doives","durent","elles","étais","être","eussent","eûtes","fusse","grâce","hormis","ils","lequel","lui","merde","moins","nos","ô","où","par","pendant","plusieurs","pourras","pouvait","pouvons","puissent","pût","quelles","revoici","se","seriez","siens","sous","taratata","tien","toute","v'lan","veut","voudra","voudrons","voulez","voulus","aie","attendu","auraient","autant","avais","ayant","beaucoup","ç'a","cela","cette","chut","coucou","depuis","devant","devra","devrons","donc","dus","en","était","eu","eusses","évohé","fussent","ha","hors","jarnicoton","les","là","mes","mon","notre","oh","ouais","parbleu","peu","pouah","pourrez","pouvant","psitt","puisses","qq.","quelqu'un","revoilà","selon","serions","sinon","soyez","tayaut","tienne","toutes","va","veux","voudrai","voudront","vouliez","voulussent","aient","au","aurais","autre","avait","ayante","bernique","ç'aura","celle","ceux","ciao","couic","des","devante","devrai","devront","dont","dussent","encontre","étant","eue","eussiez","évoé","fusses","hein","hou","je","lesdites","ma","mien","morbleu","nôtre","ohé","ouf","parce","peuchère","pour","pourriez","pouvante","pst","puissiez","qqch.","quelqu'une","rien","sera","serons","soi","soyons","taïaut","tiennes","tu","vers","via","voudraient","voulaient","voulions","voulut","aies","aucun","aurait","autres","avant","ayantes","bien","ç'aurait","celles","chacun","clic","crac","desdites","devantes","devraient","dia","du","dut","endéans","étante","eues","eussions","fi","fussiez","hem","hourra","jusque","lesdits","made","mienne","motus","nôtres","olé","ouille","pardi","peut","pourquoi","pourrions","pouvantes","pu","puissions","qqn","quels","sa","serai","seront","soient","stop","te","tiens","tudieu","veuille","vivement","voudrais","voulais","vouloir","voulût","ait","aucune","auras","aux","avec","ayants","bigre","ç'avait","celui","chacune","clac","cric","desdits","devants","devrais","diantre","dudit","dès","entre","étantes","euh","eut","fichtre","fussions","hep","hue","la","lesquelles","mais","miennes","moyennant","nous","on","oust","pardieu","peuvent","pourra","pourrons","pouvants","pue","purent","quand","qui","sacristi","seraient","ses","sois","suis","tel","toi","turlututu","veuillent","vlan","voudrait","voulait","voulons","vous","al.","aucunes","aurez","auxdites","avez","ayez","bis","ça","cependant","chaque","comme","crénom","desquelles","devez","devrait","dois","due","dû","envers","étants","eurent","eux","fors","fut","heu","hum","ladite","lesquels","malgré","miens","na","nul","ont","ouste","parmi","peux","pourrai","pourront","pouvez","pues","pus","quant","quiconque","sans","serais","si","soit","sur","telle","ton","un","veuilles","voici","voudras","voulant","voulu","vu"];
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      // filtering out stop words and numbers
      if (stopWords.indexOf(words[i].toLowerCase()) === -1 && isNaN(words[i])) {
        nonStopWords.push(words[i].toLowerCase());
      }
    }
    // console.log(nonStopWords);

    // step-2: forming an object with keywords and their count
    var keywords = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < nonStopWords.length; i++) {
      // checking if the word(property) already exists
      // if it does increment the count otherwise set it to one
      if(nonStopWords[i] in keywords) {
        keywords[nonStopWords[i]] += 1;
      } else {
        keywords[nonStopWords[i]] = 1;
      }
    }
    
    // step-3: sorting the object by first converting it to a 2D array
    var sortedKeywords = [];
    for (var keyword in keywords){
      sortedKeywords.push([keyword, keywords[keyword]])  
    }
    sortedKeywords.sort(function(a, b) {return b[1] - a[1]});
    // console.log(sortedKeywords);

    // step-4: displaying top 4 keywords and their count
    topKeywords.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < sortedKeywords.length && i < 4; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = "<b>" + sortedKeywords[i][0] + "</b>: " + sortedKeywords[i][1];
      topKeywords.appendChild(li);
    }
  }

  // displaying top keywords only if there is a word in the text area
  if (words) {
    keywordsDiv.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    keywordsDiv.style.display = "none";
  }
  
});


// readability level using readability-metrics API from Mashape
readability.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  // placeholder until the API returns the score  
  readability.innerHTML = "Fetching score...";

  var requestUrl = "https://ipeirotis-readability-metrics.p.mashape.com/getReadabilityMetrics?text=";
  var data = input.value;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', encodeURI(requestUrl + data), true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
  request.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "PQ4FOFuaR6mshI6qpnQKQvkDZQXjp1o6Zcqjsnug7GvNggTzUE");
  request.send();

  request.onload = function() {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      // Success!
      readability.innerHTML = readingEase(JSON.parse(this.response).FLESCH_READING);
    } else {
      // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
      readability.innerHTML = "Not available.";
    }
  };

  request.onerror = function() {
    // There was a connection error of some sort
    readability.innerHTML = "Not available.";
  };
});

// function to convert FLESCH READING SCORE into meaningful string.
function readingEase(num) {
  switch(true) {
    case (num <= 30):
      return "Readability: College graduate.";
      break;
    case (num > 30 && num <= 50):
      return "Readability: College level.";
      break;
    case (num > 50 && num <= 60):
      return "Readability: linéaire.";
      break;
    case (num > 60 && num <= 70):
      return "Readability: 8th - 9th grade.";
      break;
    case (num > 70 && num <= 80):
      return "Readability: fluide.";
      break;
    case (num > 80 && num <= 90):
      return "Readability: 6th grade.";
      break;
    case (num > 90 && num <= 100):
      return "Readability: 5th grade.";
      break;
    default:
      return "Not available.";
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
/* 
 Reset CSS:
 http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
 v2.0 | 20110126
 License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* Alignement à droite */
.right {
    text-align: right;
    float: no;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/* End of reset CSS */


/* border box */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;          /* Likely future */  
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
b {
 font-weight: bold;
}

/* main app styles */
body {
 width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: #FAFAFA;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 color: #111;
}

.container {
 margin: 2% auto;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

h1 {
 font-size: 3rem;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 1% 0 3%;
}

textarea {
 width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 1rem;
 resize: none;
 line-height: 1.5rem;
}

textarea:hover {
 border-color: #C0C0C0;
}

textarea:focus {
 border-color: #4D90FE;
}

.output.row {
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #DDD;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 margin: 1% 0;
 background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

.output.row div {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 42%;
 padding: 10px 25px;
 margin: 1%;
}

.output.row span {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#readability {
 width: 52%;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#readability:hover {
 background-color: #4D90FE;
 color: #FFF;
 border-radius: 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#readability:active {
 background-color: #307AF3;
}

.keywords {
 display: none;
 margin: 4% 0 0;
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-weight: 900;
}

.keywords ul {
 font-weight: 400;
 border: 1px solid #DDD;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 background-color: #F9F9F9;
 margin: 2% 0;
}

.keywords li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 44%;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 1%;
}


/* 
** Making it responsive
*/


@media (max-width: 750px) {
 body {
  width: 600px;
 }
 .output.row {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }
 .output.row span {
  font-size: 1.3rem; 
 }
 .keywords ul {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
 
 /* rewriting old styles */
 body {
  width: 95%;
 }
 .output.row {
  border: none;
  background-color: #FFF;
 }
 .output.row div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  background-color: #F9F9F9; 
 }
 .output.row span {
  font-size: 2rem; 
 }
 #readability {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
 }
 
 .keywords {
  margin: 10% auto;
 }
 
 .keywords ul {
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  margin: 5% 0;
 }

 .keywords li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JS</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <meta name="description" content="A word counter built in HTML/CSS/JS. Shows number of characters, words, reading time and readability score. Also generates a list of top keywords.">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>JS</h1>
    <textarea placeholder="Collez ici..."></textarea>
 
    <div class="right">
    <a href="javascript:window.location.reload()">Réinitialiser JS</a>
    </div>

    <div class="output row">
      <div>DURÉE ► <span id="readingTime">0</span></div>
   
      <div>NOMBRE DE MOTS ► <span id="wordCount">0</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="output row">
      <div>PHRASES ► <span id="sentenceCount">0</span></div>
      <div>PARAGRAPHES ► <span id="paragraphCount">0</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="output row">
      <div>CHARACTÈRES ► <span id="characterCount">0</span></div>
      <div id="readability">Show readability score.</div>
    </div>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="" class="txtMult"/>

    <select class="selectpicker">
    <option data-cubics='2'>X 2</option>
    <option data-cubics='3'>X 3</option>
</select>
    <span id="grandTotal">Value Shows here</span>
  </div>
</div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option20" name="option20">
    <label for="option20">+20€</label>
  </div>
    <div class="keywords">
      Mots les plus utilisés :
      <ul id="topKeywords">
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <span> PRIX :</span><span id="sp_prix"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My Word-counter is now freezed obn page - i don't know why